Does $x^p$ become greater than $\ln(x)$ for all $p \in \mathbb{R} \mid p > 0$?
With the integral test, you can show $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n \ln(n)}$ diverges.

Since, $1/x^{1.001}$ converges, this seems to imply that $x^{p} > \ln\left(x\right)$ with
$p \in \mathbb{R} \mid p > 0$ for some extremely large constant.
Does anyone know of a way to prove or disprove this ?.
It's interesting to me since it seems like it must be true, and seems like it should be impossible.

Thanks in advance !.

For the comparison test you have in mind, you only need prove $x^p>p\ln x$, or $t>\ln t$ for $t=x^p$.

Yes, you can see this with L'Hospital's rule for example:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^p}{\ln(x)} \stackrel{\text{L'H}}{=} \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{px^{p-1}}{1/x} = \lim_{x\to\infty} px^p \stackrel{p>0}{=} +\infty$$

Yes, this is true. The easiest way to see it is L'Hospital's rule. One way to explicitly get such a constant is to notice that $x^p>\ln(x)$ follows from $e^{x^p}>x$ which follows from $x^{np}/n! \geq x$ for some $n$.
From here, take $n>1/p$, then it is sufficient to have $x>(n!)^{1/(np-1)}$.
Taking just $n=2$ is fine for $p>1/2$...beyond that, it is better to use $n=\left \lceil \frac{\ln(1/p)}{p} \right \rceil$ rather than the more obvious $n=1+\lfloor 1/p \rfloor$.
